# Link C++ library to html front end

Tags: c++, html, web, cuda

I do computational research with a C++/CUDA library that does intensive number crunching. Recently I was thinking to set up a little showcase of my library on my webpage where people could work interactively with the library and see the results (plots, animations, etc.) in real time.

I have very limited html and website creating expertise. Are there libraries out there to link the html front-end to the C++/CUDA back-end? I'm developing in Linux environment but obviously I'd like my webpage to be accessed by anyone independent of their OS and/or browser.

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but you could try using the library with PHP? PHP can do your web stuff, I'm just not sure about its external library capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a little bit of research I found the [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) library which is written in C++ and used for webpage development. Based on the information on their homepage, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for:

> Typical use scenarios:

- > High performance, complex web applications which are fully personalized (and thus cannot benefit from caching), fully Ajax enabled and at the same time entirely accessible and Search Engine Optimized.
- > Web-based GUIs for embedded systems benefit from the low footprint of a C++ web application server.
- > **Web-based GUIs that require integration with (existing) C++ libraries, for example for scientific or engineering applications, or existing C++ desktop applications**

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. To do this, I used a simple library I wrote called jrb_node at https://github.com/kennethho/jrb_node

There are other libraries like cppnetlib http://cpp-netlib.org/

Basically you make a small http server that based on the request will perform some computation and return the results as an http response. You can then combine that with javascript and Ajax if you want to make it more interactive.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to consider is to use **[WebCL](http://www.khronos.org/webcl/wiki/Main_Page)**. CUDA is pretty similar to OpenCL and it should be pretty easy to convert your code to the latter. If you have other C++ code, that might be a bit of problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run CUDA on server (e.g. the users will input the parameters, push a button and your server will do number crunching) or on client (e.g. it will be user GPU that does computations)?

For server-side you should be able to use pretty much any server technology - PHP, JSP, etc. They all provide a way to integrate to "native code".
For client-side you will not be able to do with just HTML - you need to use some "fat client" technology - e.g. ActiveX, Java applet. I do not know if Silverlight or Flash have access to native code. IMHO, you might as well just write a Qt application and put a download link on your site.

Comment: What I intend is to have the heavy computation be done on the server-side where I have access to all sort of libraries etc. and have the result rendered on the client-side browser.

However, now that you mentioned, is it possible to have a code that looks on the client-side to see if it has necessary runtime libraries and if so run the code on the client machine instead?

Comment: You can't do that from pure thin client (e.g. using HTML & JS only) so you need some fat client that is downloaded and ran. Note that native calls are usually subject to security restrictions. For server-side solution though you can use pretty much anything you want. Take a look at SGI - this is the most bare-bones solution for HTTP server-side. The frontend (e.g. stuff shown to the user) can be pure HTML/JavaScript.